# Why does Ropsten faucet show "Your account is grey listed for 0 hours and 0 minutes"?

Tags: ether, ropsten, faucets

I am requesting test ether from a Ropsten faucet, but it is showing an error. Please help me to resolve this error.

[image: ropsten faucet]

Comment: It's a known issue on Ropsten Faucet.

Comment: please let me know hoe to resolve this issue

Comment: Wait for it to resolve itself

Answer (score 4):

I managed to bypass this problem by rapidly clicking the button over and over for ~ 30 seconds.

Comment: They've added a spam check so rapidly clicking for about 10 seconds gives you a 24 hour greylist for your IP and ethereum address. And doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: this is a troll answer?

Answer (score 1):

None of the faucets seemed to work for me but this one did:
https://faucet.dimensions.network/